# Mongoose connection TypeError

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mern, dbconnection

I am new to Mongodb/mongoose.

I am developing MERN stack app. Everything works apart from mongoose connection. I keep getting the error:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect') at Object ....server.js "

It seems like calling the .connect method on mongoose is the source of the error. I'll be glad if I can get solution to this issue.

My server.js code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');

const db = require("./App/models") 


const app = express();
app.use(express.json());



const db = require("./App/models");
db.mongoose
.connect(db.url, {
     useNewUrlParser: true,
     useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
   .then(() => {
     console.log("Connected to the database!");
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.log("Cannot connect to the database!", err);
     process.exit();
   });



const corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));


app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Welcome to tutorial Application." });

});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

I am trying to connect the MERN application to mongoose db

**Edit:**

Below is the index.js in the models folder:

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js"); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; 
const db = {}; db.mongoose = mongoose; 
db.url = dbConfig.url; 
db.tutorials = require("./tutorial.model.js")(mongoose); 
module.exports.db;
```

Comment: It seems `db.mongoose` is `undefined`. Can you show the models file?

Comment: Please edit your question with the code, don't post code in comment

Answer (score -1):

Below is the index.js in the models folder:

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js"); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; 
const db = {}; db.mongoose = mongoose; 
db.url = dbConfig.url; 
db.tutorials = require("./tutorial.model.js")(mongoose); 
module.exports.db;
```